# Mapping or replacing cell values with corresponding string values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns "pid", "code", "type" and "note". Each pid (patient id) is is coupled to diagnose and medicine. These have both a code, and a note (see example). Each code can have several notes. How to replace all codes with the corresponding first seen note and type? Doing a for-loop is not an option.

Note that code A for example, have both alvedon, and ipren in the IN, but only alvedon in the OUT. Doing so, I can identify them by names, instead of codes.

IN:

```
pid  code  type  note
1    A     M     alvedon
1    B     D     pain
1    C     M     ulcer
2    A     M     ipren
2    B     D     hurt
3    A     M     alvedon
3    B     D     hurt
3    C     M     stomach
4    A     M     ipren
4    B     D     pain
5    A     M     ipren
5    B     D     pain
```

OUT:

```
pid  code
1    A_M_alvedon
1    B_D_pain
1    C_M_ulcer
2    A_M_alvedon
2    B_D_pain
3    A_M_alvedon
3    B_D_pain
3    C_M_ulcer
4    A_M_alvedon
4    B_D_pain
5    A_M_alvedon
5    B_D_pain
```

I have come this far:

```
df.groupby('code').note.agg(['first'])
```

But this only gives me the grouping:

OUT:

```
code  type  note
A     alvedon
B     pain
C     ulcer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could concatenate, then groupby on the code like you're doing, and then transform:

```
In [9]: df["out"] = (
(df["code"] + "_" + df["type"] + "_" + df["note"]).groupby(df["code"]).transform("first"))

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
    pid code type     note          out
0     1    A    M  alvedon  A_M_alvedon
1     1    B    D     pain     B_D_pain
2     1    C    M    ulcer    C_M_ulcer
3     2    A    M    ipren  A_M_alvedon
4     2    B    D     hurt     B_D_pain
5     3    A    M  alvedon  A_M_alvedon
6     3    B    D     hurt     B_D_pain
7     3    C    M  stomach    C_M_ulcer
8     4    A    M    ipren  A_M_alvedon
9     4    B    D     pain     B_D_pain
10    5    A    M    ipren  A_M_alvedon
11    5    B    D     pain     B_D_pain
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. You can drop duplicates and construct your combined format. Then map to your original dataframe by `code`.

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates('code')
df2['comb'] = df2['code'] + '_' + df2['type'] + '_' + df2['note']

df['code'] = df['code'].map(df2.set_index('code')['comb'])
df = df[['pid', 'code']]

#     pid         code
# 0     1  A_M_alvedon
# 1     1     B_D_pain
# 2     1    C_M_ulcer
# 3     2  A_M_alvedon
# 4     2     B_D_pain
# 5     3  A_M_alvedon
# 6     3     B_D_pain
# 7     3    C_M_ulcer
# 8     4  A_M_alvedon
# 9     4     B_D_pain
# 10    5  A_M_alvedon
# 11    5     B_D_pain
```